# Kubernetes doesn't wait for all websocket connections to close before terminating during rolling update

Tags: websocket, kubernetes

I am trying to achieve 0 downtime during rolling update with EKS (AWS K8s service).

I have one WebSocket server and I want to ensure during the rolling update of this server, existing connections will be kept until the WebSockets are closed after the work is done.

I thought K8s rolling update feature would help me with this but it did not. I tried and it simply killed the pod while there were still connections to the WebSocket.

If I understand the [document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/#termination-of-pods) correctly, then the pod termination goes like this:

1. User signals pod deletion to K8s API
2. K8s stops routing new traffic to this pod and sends the SIGTERM signal
3. The application MUST handle this signal and start graceful termination of itself in a specified `grace-period` (default to 30s)
4. After that, K8s sends a SIGKILL signal to force terminate the pod.

If my above understanding is correct, clearly there is no way to tell K8s to:

1. Don't interrupt current connections
2. Let them run for as long as they need (they will eventually close but the period varies greatly)
3. Once all connections are closed, terminate the pod

**Question**: Is there any ways at all to make sure K8s:

1. Doesn't interrupt WebSocket connection
2. Doesn't force the application to kill the connection in a specific `grace-period`
3. Detects when all WebSocket connections are closed and kill the pod

If anyone can assist me that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a good solution for this issue? I'm facing the same issue, my application handles the sigterm signal and waits for all socket connections to disconnect before closing the server process. However, clients have their sockets disconnect, seems like the issue is in the load balancer/service layer.

Comment: Seems like this is the issue (from step 5 in the termination of pods documentation): 
"(simultaneous with 3) Pod is removed from endpoints list for service, and are no longer considered part of the set of running Pods for replication controllers. Pods that shutdown slowly cannot continue to serve traffic as load balancers (like the service proxy) remove them from their rotations."

Answer (score 2):

For mission critical application, go for customised blue-green deployments.

First deploy new version deployment with new selector and when all POD replicas are UP and ready to serve traffic, switch the service selector to point to new version deployment.

After this send the kill switch to older version which gracefully handles and disconnect all clients. So all new reconnections are forwarded to new version which is already set to serve traffic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `lifecycle hook` in kubernetes pod lifecycle which have a `preStop hook`. This hook will run just before the termination of your pod.

```
lifecycle:
  postStart:
    exec:
      command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo Hello from the postStart handler > /usr/share/message"]
  preStop:
    exec:
      command: ["/bin/sh","-c","nginx -s quit; while killall -0 nginx; do sleep 1; done"]
```

You can have your script to kill all the connections and wait for the connection to terminate and then only the pod will terminate.

Comment: `have your script to kill all the connections and wait for the connection to terminate` If I kill all the connections, I am forcefully closing the connections. The connections are interrupted, which is not what I want. I want the connection to keep run as per usual. When they're done their intended jobs, they will close the connections themselves.

Comment: Ideally, your application should handle the graceful termination when it receive SIGTERM, but even if in case it is not present. You should have some mechanism to trigger the graceful termination of your application. This may include stopping the long lived connection or storing some state. All these things are specific to application and must be handled at the app level only.

Comment: Think about it this way. 0 downtime means end users won't feel anything during the upgrade. In my case, users are using a websocket, and they expect it to run until they decide to end it. How can I gracefully terminate the pod when I receive the SIGTERM without letting the end users know that?

Comment: You'll have to keep the Pod that has that ESTABLISHED connection alive (in Terminating state) for as long as the connection persists. You can do this with preStop hooks and described before. Did you manage to do this in the meantime?